# Romance in Mass Effect?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect

So, I started playing Mass Effect 3 and I imported my saved game from Mass Effect 2, I had a romance with Tali and I wanna know that even if I imported the romance within the saved game, am I able to romance somebody else in the game or will I have to continue romancing Tali?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Some romances in mass Effect 3 must be continued from Mass Effect 2- those won't be available- but romancing Tali in a previous game won't stop you romancing someone new.

By picking the right dialogue options, a male Shepherd who previously romanced Tali would be able to romance one of the following:

- Tali'Zorah
- Ashley Williams
- Steve Cortez
- Kaiden Alenko
- Liara T'soni
- Diana Allers (note that this does not grant the achievement)